# points aren't aligned with the x axis on flot chart

Tags: javascript

I've got flot data where the points on the xaxis aren't aligned with the lines.

specifically, take a look at this photo:[image: flot chart]

this is the raw data that I'm using:

```
[0] : [1327305600000,1989],
[1] : [1327392000000,3222.33333333333],
[2] : [1327564800000,1481.5],
[3] : [1327651200000,2061],
[4] : [1327910400000,1434],
[5] : [1327996800000,1504.75],
[6] : [1328083200000,1422.4]
```

and this is the javascript that I'm passing to flot:

```
$.plot($("#something"), [datapoints], {
    series: {
         lines: { show: true , shadowSize:0},
         points: { show: true }
    },
    xaxis: { 
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
        reserveSpace: true
    },
    clickable: true,
    hoverable: true,
    legend: {
        show: true
    }
    
});
```

specifically, look at the second point.  The timestamp for it is 1327392000000, and you can see from the following code that this should be aligned with the 1/24/2012 x-axis point, but it's not.

**var d = new Date(1327392000000);**
*=> Tue Jan 24 00:00:00 PST 2012*

If there's any way I can workaround this, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this:

- http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=608

the time should be UTC, not PST.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by passing date in the format YYYY-MM-DD to this statement:

`new Date(dateInYYYY_MM_DD).getTime();`