# jQuery Flot.js: Line chart points not centered with x-axis grid line

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

My points do not appear centered with the grid line of the x-axis as visible in the screenshot below:

[image]

The options I am using are as follows:

```
    var options = {
      grid: {
        show: true,
        aboveData: false,
        color: "#3f3f3f",
        labelMargin: 10,
        axisMargin: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor: null,
        minBorderMargin: 5,
        clickable: true,
        hoverable: true,
        autoHighlight: true,
        mouseActiveRadius: 100
      },
      series: {
        lines: {
          show: true,
          fill: true,
          lineWidth: 2,
          steps: false
        },
        points: {
          show: true,
          radius: 4.5,
          symbol: "circle",
          lineWidth: 3.0
        }
      },
      legend: {
        position: "ne",
        margin: [0, -15],
        noColumns: 0,
        labelBoxBorderColor: null,
        labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
          // just add some space to labes
          return label + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        },
        width: 40,
        height: 1
      },
      colors: chartColours,
      shadowSize: 0,
      tooltip: true, //activate tooltip
      tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%s: %y.0",
        xDateFormat: "%d/%m",
        shifts: {
          x: -30,
          y: -50
        },
        defaultTheme: false
      },
      yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        tickDecimals:0
      },
      xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        minTickSize: tickSize,
        timeformat: tformat,
        min: chartMinDate,
        max: chartMaxDate
      }
    };
```

My data set is a time-series, and the labels values is also coming from the same data set so the dates should line up with the points. However it is offset while no option for this exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution of this question?

Comment: I did not. I might give this another look soon so if I find a solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from this link

[points aren't aligned with the x axis on flot chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106283/points-arent-aligned-with-the-x-axis-on-flot-chart)

And

https://code.google.com/archive/p/flot/issues/608

It seems Flot chart requires the time in UTC format.

For me it worked by just adding the "**`timezone:"browser"`**" in "**`xaxis`**".

After addition, my "xaxis" looks like below :

```
 xaxis: {
           mode: "time",
           minTickSize: [1, "day"],
           timeformat: "%d-%b-%y",
           timezone:"browser",
           min: min date value define here,
           max: max date value define here
        }
```